# Transit Visa for Indian Citizen in Istanbul

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, turkey, turkish-airlines, ist

I am an Indian citizen living in the US on an H-1B visa. I am travelling back to India from the US via Istanbul on a Turkish airlines single ticket. My stopover is ~3 hours only. Do I need a transit visa for just transiting via Istanbul? I do not plan to go out of the airport.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a transit visa. They mention in it here : [Türkiye MFA FAQ](https://www.mfa.gov.tr/frequently-asked-questions.en.mfa#:%7E:text=Do%20I%20need%20to%20get,to%20the%20nearest%20Turkish%20Representation.)

Comment: Welcome to [travel.se] ozcnakd! Please ensure you go through the tour and at least get familiar with [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask].